# Search for a string and output values corresponding to that string

Tags: excel, vba, function, loops, if-statement

Good day

My aim is to create a list that grows horizontally (by columns). Table 1 has five columns and a number of rows subjected to increase, (column A-Main task), (column   B-sub-task), (column C- resource 1 to carry out the task),(column D- resource 2 to carry out the same task),(column E- resource 3 to carry out the same task). NB: Each main task can have multiple sub-tasks, if this is the case, a number of cells (for main task) will be merged to correspond to  multiple sub-tasks corresponding to the main task.

Table 2 has a list of all resources listed in column A. These resources may have/have not appeared in Table 2 (column C/D/E), i.e., assigned a sub task/main task.

The code I have is meant to search for each resource in table 1, searching for tasks and subtasks it is assigned to and output those results as shown in the image.

The plan in the code creation is: The code must use resource names in column A-Table 2 as an index, use it to search for the resource in table 1 in the first column, if it finds a match, then output value in the table. And continues to search for the same resource and output if it finds it. Next search for the same resource in the next column, then the next.

Once its done searching for resource aa, it searches for resource bb in column c, then d, then the last one. Inputting results values as it goes.

Your assistance in modifying what I have is greatly appreciated.

In the below code, the table tables are in different sheets. This is fine and can be implemented as well.

```vb
Sub SearchResourceNames()
    
    'Declare variables
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim resource As String, task As String, col As Long
    
    'Set the worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2")
    
    'Initialize variables
    i = 2
    j = 2
    k = 2
    col = 2
    
    'Loop through the resources in table 2
    For Each r In ws2.Range("A1:A10")
    
    'Get the resource name
    resource = r.Value
    
    'Initialize flag to indicate if task has been found
    found = False
    
    'Loop through the tasks in table 1
    For Each c In ws1.Range("A:A")
    
    'If the resource is found in the current task,
    If c.Value = resource Then
    
    'Set the flag to indicate that the task has been found
    found = True
    
    'Get the task name
    task = c.Offset(0, col).Value
    
    'If the task has not been found before,
    If Not ws2.Range("B" & k).Value = task Then
    
    'Add the task name to the output column
    ws2.Range("B" & k).Value = task
    
    'Increment the output column index
    k = k + 1
    
    End If
    
    End If
    
    Next c
    
    'If the task was not found in any of the tasks,
    If Not found Then
    
    'Print a message to the user
    MsgBox "The resource " & resource & " was not found in any of the tasks."
    
    End If
    
    Next r
    
    'Move to the next column in table 2
    col = col + 1
    
    'Reset the output column index
    k = 2
    
End Sub
```

Data and desired output:

[image]

Current-undesired output

[image]

Comment: My apologies. Let me edit.

Comment: Needs a screenshot of Table1

Comment: Hi Tim. I have  re-edited. There's links that show desired and undesired outputs. Thanks.

Comment: This may help with tables  https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Transform Data

[image]
[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateResources()
    
    ' Constants
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Table1"
    Const SRC_MAIN_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const SRC_SUB_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const SRC_FIRST_DATA_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Table2"
    Const DST_FIRST_TABLE_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_HEADERS As String = "Resource,To-Do List"
    Const DST_MAIN_SUB_DELiMiTER As String = "-"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_DATA_CELL)
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    
    With sfCell.CurrentRegion
        Set srg = sfCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - sfCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - sfCell.Column)
    End With

    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    If scCount < 3 Then
        MsgBox "Not enough columns.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Unique resources to the keys, and the resources' rows to the keys
    ' of another (inner) dictionary held by each item of the outer dictionary.
    
    Dim rDict As Object: Set rDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    rDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, rStr As String, rMaxCount As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For sc = 1 To scCount
            If sc <> SRC_MAIN_COLUMN And sc <> SRC_SUB_COLUMN Then
                rStr = CStr(sData(sr, sc))
                If Len(rStr) > 0 Then
                    If Not rDict.Exists(rStr) Then
                        Set rDict(rStr) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    End If
                    If Not rDict(rStr).Exists(sr) Then
                        rDict(rStr)(sr) = Empty
                        If rDict(rStr).Count > rMaxCount Then
                            rMaxCount = rDict(rStr).Count
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next sc
    Next sr
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = rDict.Count + 1
    
    If dcCount = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No resources found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Join mains and subs. Each row to the keys and each 'join' to the items
    ' of a dictionary
    
    Dim msDict As Object: Set msDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim mStr As String, cmStr As String, sStr As String, tStr As String
    Dim IsMainFound As Boolean
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        mStr = CStr(sData(sr, SRC_MAIN_COLUMN))
        If IsMainFound Then
            If Len(mStr) = 0 Then
                mStr = cmStr
            Else
                cmStr = mStr
            End If
            sStr = CStr(sData(sr, SRC_SUB_COLUMN))
            If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
                tStr = mStr & DST_MAIN_SUB_DELiMiTER & sStr
                msDict(sr) = tStr
            End If
        Else
            If Len(mStr) > 0 Then
                IsMainFound = True
                sr = sr - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Using the information from the dictionaries,
    ' generate the destination (result) array.
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To msDict.Count + 1, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim dHeaders() As String: dHeaders = Split(DST_HEADERS, ",")
    dData(1, 1) = dHeaders(0)
    dData(1, 2) = dHeaders(1)
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1
    
    Dim orKey, irKey, dc As Long
    
    For Each orKey In rDict.Keys
        dr = dr + 1
        dData(dr, 1) = orKey
        dc = 1
        For Each irKey In rDict(orKey).Keys
            If msDict.Exists(irKey) Then
               dc = dc + 1
               dData(dr, dc) = msDict(irKey)
            End If
        Next irKey
    Next orKey

    ' Destination

    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_TABLE_CELL)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, dcCount)
    
    With drg
        
        ' Clear and write.
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Value = dData
        
        ' Format.
        
        ' Merge and center second header.
        With .Resize(1, dcCount - 1).Offset(, 1)
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        ' All borders
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        ' All headers
        With .Resize(1)
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        ' All entire columns
        With .EntireColumn
            .AutoFit
            ' Resource columns only
            With .Resize(, dcCount - 1).Offset(, 1)
                .ColumnWidth = 4
            End With
        End With
        ' Resource data only (no headers)
        With .Resize(dr - 1, dcCount - 1).Offset(1, 1)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        
        ' etc.
    
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Resources generated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a Dictionary of all resources. Every entry in that resource Dictionary then again gets a Dictionary of all tasks that the resource needs to take care about.

Only after building the complete Dictionary, it will be dumped into the result sheet.

If you are not familiar with Dictionaries: There is a lot of documentation around, [for example here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/). Note that I'm using early binding, so you have to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

The code for building the resource Dictionary is rather straight forward. For speed reasons, I first read the complete data of `Table1` into a 2-dimensional array (I called it `data`). Then the code loops over all rows of all resource columns and reads the resource name. If it is not in the dictionary (it is "new"), we create a new Dictionary (`taskDict`) for the entry. Then the task is added to the task Dictionary and the resource is added to the resource Dictionary.

```
Function fillResourceDict() As Dictionary
    
    ' (1) Read data from table1
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long, col As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
        lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        ' Fill in empty values in column 1 (because of the unholy merged cells)
        For row = 3 To lastRow
            If IsEmpty(data(row, 1)) Then data(row, 1) = data(row - 1, 1)
        Next row
    End With

    ' (2) Build the resouce-Dictionary. Loop over all recource columns
    Dim resourceDict As New Dictionary
    For row = 3 To lastRow
        For col = 3 To lastCol
            Dim resource As String, task As String, taskDict As Dictionary
            resource = data(row, col)
            If resource <> "" Then
                If resourceDict.Exists(resource) Then
                    ' Read the taskDict from existing resource
                    Set taskDict = resourceDict(resource)
                Else
                    ' New resource: Create a new Dictionary
                    Set taskDict = New Dictionary
                End If
                task = data(row, 1) & "-" & data(row, 2)
                taskDict(task) = task    ' add Task
                Set resourceDict(resource) = taskDict
            End If
        Next col
    Next row
            
    Set fillResourceDict = resourceDict
End Function
```

Now all that's left to do is to call this function and fill the result into table2:

```
Sub fillToDoList()
    
    Dim resourceDict As Dictionary
    Set resourceDict = fillResourceDict
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        Dim resource As Variant, row As Long
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Resource"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "ToDo list"
        row = 2
        
        For Each resource In resourceDict.Keys
            .Cells(row, 1) = resource
            Dim taskDict As Dictionary
            Set taskDict = resourceDict(resource)
            .Cells(row, 2).Resize(1, taskDict.Count).Value = taskDict.Keys
            row = row + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```